# Searching for an exact phrase in PDF with Preview

Tags: pdf, preview, search

I used to do this all the time. For example, I'd search for "blue house" (two words, with double quotes) and it would find the text "the *blue house* on the corner", but not "paint the house green and blue".

Lately it doesn't work. Did they remove the feature? Any way to get it back? I think it stopped working in macOS 12, but at the moment I'm on 13.0 Ventura. (Preview 11.0)

Comment: I don't have macOS 13.0 installed yet but I have Preview 11.0 running on macOS v12.6.1 and I can confirm that I can search for an exact multi-word phrase, i.e. get `the blue house` but not `the blue and green house` in a PDF document via Preview using double quotes, i.e. "blue house", in the search window.

Comment: @Alper It no longer works that way. It seems to be a bug (and annoying one at that) because the [Apple macOS Ventura documentation](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/preview/prvw2014/mac) says double quotes is how to do it. Unfortunately it doesn't. The accepted answer is how you have to do it in Ventura (I seem to recall maybe 12 too but not sure now).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I can't be sure the following solution will work in your case because it might be different under macOS 13 and I'm running macOS 12.5:

Click the down-arrow head next to the search field in Preview and make sure `Exact Phrase` is checked. Here is a screenshot:

[image: exact phrase checked image]

Comment: This is correct in Ventura yes. I seem to recall in 12 it also was this way. I deem it a bug and an annoying bug at that. I think bug because the [Apple macOS Ventura documentation](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/preview/prvw2014/mac) suggests double quotes should work.

Comment: That's a morning wasted trying to work out how to search for phrases. Searching with quotes no longer works in Finder. Using pdfgrep for now. BTW, to see the above toolbar go to View -> Show Toolbar

Comment: Worse yet, once 'Exact Phrase' is checked, it remains so even if you close and re-open the document.